# Updating a collection the RESTful way

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I'm in a situation where I have something similar to shopping cart. I have a set of products with known IDs I then want to create a subset with modified prices and later modify this subset

Superset

```
[{  
   "productId":1,
   "price":1.99
},
{  
  "productId":2,
  "price":2.99
},
{  
  "productId":3,
  "price":3.99
},
{  
   "productId":4,
   "price":4.99
}]
```

...

Modified Subset

```
[{  
   "productId":1,
   "price":1.59
},
{  
  "productId":3,
  "price":2.59
}]
```

Then I want to modify the subset again to look like

```
[{  
   "productId":1,
   "price":1.79
},
{  
  "productId":2,
  "price":3.59
}]
```

All I can think of is client sending a POST request like

```
{  
   "productsAdded":[  
      {  
         "productId":2,
         "price":3.59
      }
   ],
   "productsModified":[  
      {  
         "productId":1,
         "price":1.79
      }
   ],
   "productsDeleted":[  
      {  
         "productId":3,
         "price":2.59
      }
   ]
}
```

The constraints are that I would like to avoid multiple calls to correct verbs and not send the entire subset. As the actual objects have many more fields and there are thousands of objects in a subset. The update then saves the state triggers a long running fire and forget task.

The problem I see with this is that client potentially has to create a delta of 
the state and the server has to reconstruct the state from the message.

This might not be a bad approach, but I am wondering if there are alternative solutions

Comment: Your superset and subset lack consistency.

Comment: @AlanLarimer That's by design, I want the products in subset to have different prices from original and have the ability to modify them and any other fields I may have in the subset. I guess calling the collections sets might not be quite correct here

Comment: I read it as Superset -> Subset -> ModifiedSubset, but you are really stating Superset -> ModifiedSubset -> AgainModifiedSubset?

Comment: Yea, that's what I meant. The subset entities just have to have id from superset (don't have to worry about creating IDs) and can be modified many times without affecting superset. Think of it as overrides for product prices that the user can create, update, delete and all changes made need to happen in single transaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Updating a collection the RESTful way

The [Atom Publishing Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) is built around the idea of modifying collections of atom entries in the REST architectural style.  You might start out by reviewing that design.

> All I can think of is client sending a POST request like

That's really close to a [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) representation.

The idea is that if the client and the server share the same (usually standardized) understanding of the media-type, then they can continue to collaborate even as they are developed independently.

So using POST to pass a JSONPatch representation of the change to the resource is a good starting point; if you don't like JSONPatch (perhaps because it is domain agnostic), you could define your own more specific media type and use that.

(Note: though the message type is called "patch", you don't actually need to use the [PATCH method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) in your API.  POST on its own, PATCH on its own, or both are all acceptable alternatives.)

Comment: Interesting, never knew about JSON Patch. It seems different from HTTP PATCH which adds to the confusion. I'll look into it, it seems like standardized version of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score -1):

Your proposed solution has all of the caveats you mentioned and more.  Suggestions:

1. Modify each object individually through independent requests using
   the appropriate HTTP verbs POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
2. Return the entire collection to be processed on the server using the
   appropriate HTTP verb PUT.
3. Return the partial collection to be processed on the server using the appropriate HTTP verb PATCH.

Additional reference links:

- https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/
- http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789
- http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post

Comment: He is absolutely using the POST verb according to the spec.

Comment: POST is for creating new entities. So unless that *modification* is an entity being created and returning a new reference to it so that it can be retrieved later, then POST is incorrect.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3: "The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics. For example, POST is used for the following functions (among others): [...] Appending data to a resource's existing representation(s)."

Comment: You are misreading the spec. "process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics" is not "creates a resource", it is "does something with the contents of the resource". POST is the catchall verb for when you need to do anything that another verb doesn't provide to you. Here is a discussion on the appropriateness of using POST for performing non-create actions: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post. The author is Roy Fielding, who defined REST and wrote the HTTP spec.